# Modular Zend Framework app & Doctrine integration and usage

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, yaml, zend-framework-modules

I need help, cause I am little stuck on this.
I have set up a modular Zend Framework app. Also using -- https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD- -- i integrated Doctrine 2.

My directory structure is like this:
-aplication/
--default/    --module1
---config
---controllers/
---forms/
---models/
---templates/
---test/
--maintenance  --module2
---config
---controllers/
---forms/
---models/
---templates/
---test/
-config
--Bootstrap.php
--aplication.ini
-library/
--Zend/
--Doctrine/
--doctrine.php
--cli-config.php
-sites/
--site1/
---index.php

I have my databse created. I will use some tools to generate YAML files from database.
The next step I want is to generate model classes from these YAML files. 
I spend days searching, but I just coudn't find solution to generate classes to models folder of each module. OK, so I would solve the problem by generating these classes in one directory and then move it to their 'original' destination (models folders).

I need help on how to generate these classes. I am developing in Windows, and that is where I want to generate this.
I suppose I have to open cms, point to location of doctrine.php (in library folder) and enter command php doctrine.php + some arguments. But when I do that i have:
 **[InvalidArgumentException]

 There are no commands defined in the "" namespace.**

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?
I will also try to contact author of these files https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD- to ask for explanation.

Thanks in advance. I would really appreciate your help.
If you need I can write some of my code from Bootstrap and application.ini if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  generate the class from YML file .It is possible to use MySQL workbench to sync the database tables and then use the MySQL workbench YML file generator  plugin  to generate the YML files . Hope it helps.